# Blender has weird fuzzy misbehaving icon in launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, blender

I got Blender 2.58 (stable) from blender.org (downloaded the package, extracted it). Everything works fine, but the only thing that bugs me is that the icon in the launcher (when I open it) is really fuzzy. I guess that's no big deal, but when I select "Keep in Launcher" and close Blender, the icon doesn't work when I try to open it again.

Then, I created a Launcher on my desktop with the path to the blender executable, slapped on a shiny new non-fuzzy .svg icon that came with the package, and dragged the (desktop) Launcher to my (Unity) Launcher. Now, when I click on the new launcher, it keeps showing the flashing thing that says it's opening the program, and then the old fuzzy icon comes back but doesn't replace the new icon. Even after Blender opens, the new icon is still flashing.

What is wrong with my launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use Blender from the ppa:
`ppa:irie/blender`
This will provide you with the svn version (weekly). These are usually stable, but if you want it to be truly stable, you can lock the version in synaptic. You can also get Blender 2.4 from this PPA.

To add this to your Unity Launcher, drag the icon from the Dash.*

The challenge with using Blender from the tarball on their website is that it will lack some of the desktop integration features you would get from installing a package that is built for the specific OS/distro.

Comment: This is very well, but when I run the application, icon doesn't show up in the (Unity) Launcher at all.

Comment: Nevermind... You have to drag the icon from the dash to the launcher.

Comment: FYI the chelep ppa is no more

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are missing is a `.desktop` file to tell the launcher about Blender.

Assuming you installed to `/opt/blender`, copy the following to `/usr/share/applications/blender.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Blender
Comment=Blender 3D Graphics
Exec=/opt/blender/blender
Icon=/opt/blender/icons/scalable/apps/blender.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3D;Application;
```

Then search for blender in the dash, launch, right click the launcher icon and check *Lock to Launcher*

Comment: Is the delimiter just the `Icon` line?